# Fast way of scanning entire image pixels in android

Tags: c#, java, android

I want to "sum" the pixels (r + g + b) inside an image. In C#, i did it in 5 milliseconds. My fastest way in android (Galaxy 4) is 101 milliseconds. I have no idea what is the faster way, or even if there is a faster way.

My C# (unsafe) code is:

```
        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;

        BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
            nWidth, nHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        int remain = data.Stride - data.Width * 3;

        byte* ptr = (byte*)data.Scan0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nHeight; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nWidth; j++)
            {
                b += ptr[0];
                g += ptr[1];
                r += ptr[2];
                ptr += 3;
            }
            ptr += remain;
        }
```

In android, what I did is:

```
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("./sdcard/me.jpg");
    image.getPixels(pixels, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
    {
        sum += Color.red(pixels[i]) + Color.green(pixels[i]) + Color.blue(pixels[i]);
    }
```

Is there a better or a faster way?

Comment: Did you test the Java code for which part takes so long. Also, is the c# code running on a regular PC or WindowsPhone?

Comment: 58 milliseconds in pure Java. Better than the android but still slower then C#. 
I'm testing on my regular PC. Maybe it has better GPU than my phone, but they have about the same power in the CPU, which handels the colors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing ((col >> 16) & 0xFF) + ((col >> 8) & 0xFF) + (col & 0xFF) instead of Color.red(pixels[i]) + Color.green(pixels[i]) + Color.blue(pixels[i]) (inlining the funcs instead of calling them) lowered the time from 101 milliseconds to to just 10 milliseconds :) This is an acceptable time...

Answer (score 0):

Rarely will a phone GPU/CPU be close to a PC, so you're not exactly comparing apples to apples here.  That being said, there are several approaches you could take to speed this up:

1. Split your code to do the summation in multiple Java threads
2. Write a NDK library to do the summation work in native C/C++ code
3. Do #2 with threading
4. Switch the algorithm to use RenderScript to do the summation.

Other than #2 above, you'd have to rework your algorithm to be able to be parallelized.  Each has their pros and cons.  If you'd like to see a working example of some number crunching with some performance numbers, check out the presentation and demo from my AnDevCon San Francisco 2013 classes:

http://www.hiqes.com/android-dev-con-sf-2013/